# Is Cocoa's NSMutableArray sparse?

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, sparse-array

If I create an NSMutableArray that might have up to 2^16 elements, but will mostly be empty, will I be wasting space or is NSMutableArray implemented as a sparse array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elements in an `NSArray` can't be empty and there's no "default" value. To represent `nil`, you'd usually use the singleton `[NSNull null]`, which is still a reference to an object so it consumes memory (the pointer). I'd consider using `NSDictionary` (or `NSMutableDictionary`) with numeric (`NSNumber`) keys instead.

Comment: For the record, `NSPointerArray` does allow `NULL` elements.

Answer (score 1):

No neither `NSArray` nor `NSMutableArray` are sparse arrays. If you have an array with 5000 entries with everything except 4999 set to `[NSNull null]` it is still taking the space of 5000 entries.

Similarly, an `NSPointerArray` will have the space for 5000 entries with all the entries `NULL` except index 4999.

I developed a sparse array object using an `NSMutableDictionary` as described by OMZ. With this there is only *space* for the one entry. This *space*, however, holds both the index and object, and there is the overhead of converting the index values to `NSNumber`s. So although they can be used anyplace an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` can be there would be a performance penalty. This is a classic speed / space tradeoff.

See https://github.com/LavaSlider/DSSparseArray

Answer (score -3):

An NSArray object is static (or immutable) in the sense that it must be populated at the moment you create it, either by using -initWithObjects, +arrayWithObjects, or by using the contents of an already existing array with -initWithArray, etc. You cannot add objects later on.

There is a concrete mutable subclass (called NSMutableArray) which allows for adding and removing objects dynamically as needed. However when you initialize it in an empty state (either by -initWithCapacity: or +arrayWithCapacity:) what you specify as the initial length is just a hint (the array is created with enough memory to hold that number of objects), howerver it can be expanded as necessary. So yes, in this case, it'll be a sparse array.

Best,

Comment: Yes, I meant NSMutableArray. O:-) Thanks!

Comment: An expandable array is not the same as a [sparse array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array). A sparse array could have 1000 elements, with all elements except for the last one being empty. It would actually store only one element, while there's no way for an `NSArray` to have an object at the 1000th position without the other 999 positions being filled with objects.

Comment: -1 because the answer is not correct (not against you, but so others don't take it falsely as correct). See omz's comment and see omz's answer, which is the correct one.